# see details of a database in terminal ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ssh, terminal

I want to see database details such as users that access this database or collation type in mysql, ssh terminal commands.

please help me.
thank you..

Comment: you can know more about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575347/list-of-users-accessing-database

Answer (score 0):

You can run mysql console client with --execute parameter for this purpose:

```
$ mysql -h {hostname} -u {user} -p{password} -e "SHOW PROCESSLIST"
```

This will produce output similar to the next one:

```
+----+---------+-----------------+---------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| Id | User    | Host            | db      | Command | Time | State | Info             |
+----+---------+-----------------+---------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| 1  | root    | {hostname}:3786 | NULL    | Query   |    0 | NULL  | SHOW PROCESSLIST |
+----+---------+-----------------+---------+---------+------+-------+------------------+
```